# Image view not showing in screen overlay

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a overlay on the screen just like facebook messenger, the overlay is working but it is showing only the textview present in the layout but it is not showing the images in the same layout

I have tried rebuilding the project, cleaning it but it doesnt seem to fix the issue

```
    windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.OPAQUE)

    //Inflate the chat head layout we created
    val visitorAlertView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.overlay_visitor_alert, null)





    windowManager.addView(visitorAlertView, params)
```

it should appear like this, but it is not showing only the images

[image]
[image]

here is my layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/root_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">
        <TextView
                android:text="Naveen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/visitor_name" android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#fff" android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu" android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="147dp" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-57dp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView7" android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/app_name_short"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView11" android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#fff" android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu" android:textSize="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginStart="0dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/overlay_visitor_alert"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView11" android:textColor="#fff" android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="149dp"
                android:layout_height="108dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/user_round_icon"
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp" android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/overlay_accept"
                android:id="@+id/visitor_accept" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/visitor_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/overlay_cancel"
                android:id="@+id/imageView9" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/visitor_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/visitor_accept"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using **vector drawables**? if yes, then consider using it with `AppCompatImageView`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I believe it will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat, as mention in documentation

Comment: Yes, but sometimes, some of older Os versions failed to load it (prior to lollipop).

Comment: i have been using the real device with api level 24

Comment: @NaveenKingmaker try to use src instead of srcCompat for test

Comment: @anber it worked, please write it as an answer so that i can make it as accepted answer.

Comment: @JeelVankhede answer worked for me, since I'm using vector drawable compat I have to use srcCompat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `src` instead of `srcCompat`.

Comment: you should add more explanation to your answer. This has been flagged as VLQ